# How can I make particles not rotate after lay on the surface?

Tags: particles, physics

I want to make the falling autumn leaves. 
I did a system of particles that rotate in flight.

How can I make them not rotate after lay on the surface?

Comment: Check your friction setting. Up the friction for the material and the floor the particle gets in contact with.

Comment: Could you use the "die on hit" setting, and then turn on render for dead particles...?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly make the Particles die on contact (by checking the option in the collision tab) and display dead Particles (In Particle Settings)

Comment: Please elaborate your answer (add screenshots, explain what those things do, etc.) and I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Go the collision settings for the surface the leaves are landing on and increase the friction setting as high as possible. If the particles are still rotating upon collision you can increase the particle's friction as well.

Comment: Have you tried? I have same issue here and friction setting has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

I have other idea:
Decrease Lifetime to end up particle animation and tick  Died under Particle Render tab.